# Is there a declaring-type object pointer on stack?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Let's say I have:

```
class Animal { }
class Dog : Animal { }
```

And in the main method:

```
Dog dog = new Dog();
Animal animal = dog;
```

Now there is one instance of `Dog` on the heap, and two variables on the stack, with the same reference stored in them. The next step is

```
   //Try to invoke dog.Bark() programatically
   //Try to invoke animal.Bark() programatically
```

The latter fails at run time, because `animal` hasn't a `Bark` method. So there must be something different on stack, for the two variables. What's the difference resulting in the run time error?

Comment: Could you make your question clearer?

Comment: Why do you think there' _anything_ on the stack?

Comment: @Rune FS - Because local variables in functions are created on stack.

Comment: It could be argued that you are making unwarranted assumptions here.  C# is an abstract language and the implementation details you are talking about are not part of the C# spec, they are just a feature of the current Microsoft implementation of the langauge.  A reference is not the same thing as a pointer in the C# spec - see this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/02/17/references-are-not-addresses.aspx

Comment: @James Gaunt: It's not an unwarranted assumption.

Comment: You read that article fast. It's written by one of the main developers of the C# compiler and clearly states that references are not addresses.  A reference is a reference, it's conceptual.  The implementation underlying is not part of C# spec, so you can't really talk about C# having pointers or addresses.

Comment: @janea they could but they might be heap allocated as well

Comment: @James Gaunt: I know what you are talking about. But even correct the *words* in my question ,the question remains, see my edit.

Comment: The two expressions are the same when it comes to the binaries compiled for each. The local for each will be of different types but the IL for the construction and assignment is identical

Comment: @James: I have corrected my words in the question.

Comment: After your edit. Yes there something different when declaring Them different. When you declare as Animal you tell the compiler this will always be an animal but could be any animal but it's compile time not run time

Comment: It would have saved us both of us a lot of time if you'd **asked the actual question first** rather than asking a question about implementation details of the runtime. You are probably building the expression tree incorrectly; it is very easy to get wrong. My advice: start a new question where you show **in detail** how you are building the expression tree and describe **in detail** what errors you are getting. This vague description of "I tried to build an expression tree and I got an error but I'm not going to tell you how I built it or what error I got" leaves us nothing to go on!

Comment: Your conclusion that "there must be something different on the stack" is incorrect; the exact same data is on the stack in both variables: a managed reference to a heap-allocated instance of Dog. There's something else going on here. Some advice when asking questions about things going wrong: do not assume that you know what is going wrong. If you knew what was going wrong then you wouldn't be asking the question! Don't go to your doctor and ask "what are the treatments for pneumonia?" -- you don't know if you have pneumonia yet. **Describe the symptoms and get a diagnosis first.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correctly deducing a number of implementation details.

Before going into those details, some terms.  There are three kinds of storage:

- unmanaged storage
- managed storage
- temporary storage

Unmanaged storage is outside the scope of your question. Managed storage is what we'll call "the heap".  Temporary storage is "the stack" or registers if the jitter is clever and registers are available, but as a simplifying assumption lets ignore registers and just call the temporary storage pool "the stack".

There are four kinds of types:

- unmanaged pointers
- value types
- references, aka, managed pointers
- the actual instances of reference types

Unmanaged pointers are outside the scope of your question. C# allows you to manipulate references ("managed pointers") and value types directly; contents of reference type instances are only manipulated via references and are always on the heap in the CLR implementation. (Nothing stops the jitter from creating an instance of reference type on the stack if it has enough smarts to know that the object never needs garbage collection and does not survive the method, but in practice our jitters do not do so to my knowledge.)

The other three kinds of things can be on the stack or the heap as necessary, depending on their lifetimes.

> In my main method an instance of Dog is created and assigned to a variable named dog. I know what happens on the heap, assuming it locates from the address 0x00FFFF.

You are assuming (correctly) that managed references are implemented as addresses in a flat 32 bit address space. (That would not actually be a legal heap address, but we'll let it slide.) Of course, an implementation of the CLR need not use raw addresses as references. They could be opaque handles into a table controlled by the GC, for example.

> Currently I only know on the stack the space for dog has its value 0x00FFFFF, but I'm 100% sure somewhere else in the space for dog has its declaring type.

By its "declaring" type I think you mean the actual runtime type of the instance, Dog. This is a confusing use of "declaring". Instances are not "declared"; instances are " allocated". *Variables* are "declared" and the variable has the declared type "Animal".

Yes, somewhere in the actual instance data allocated for "new Dog()" there is a "token" that describes the runtime type of the object. If the exact details of how the token works are important to you, ask another question.

> I want to know a detail explaination of the stack space for dog, currently I know there is a reference address there, anything else?

Your question is ambiguous because there are two variables on the stack and neither of them are named "dog".

At runtime the stack space just contains the managed reference to the heap space allocated for the instance. The C# compiler knows that the stack space for dog1 was of compile-time type managed-reference-to-Animal and the stack space for dog2 was of compile time type managed-reference-to-Dog. The jitter therefore knows that information as well. The jitter keeps information about that in its own data structures; it does not pollute the stack.  The jitter can keep this information around for optimizations, or for debugging purposes. Or it can throw it away if it doesn't need that information anymore.

This again is an implementation detail; the jitter is perfectly free to put any additional information on the stack it pleases.

Comment: Sorry for my bad expression of the question. I have edited, more C# code, maybe now it's more clearer what I'm asking? Thanks.

Comment: Actually I didn't test with the `LambdaExpression`, they are just I *imagined* to express my question better! But anyway you answered it and I got to know what I want to know now.

Answer (score 1):

References are located on stack and CLR knows kind of reference it is working with. The memory pointed by the reference is allocated on the heap. In your example both references could point to the same place in memory but CLR interprets the differently because of reference type.

Comment: What do you mean the CLR interpretes it differently because of different refence type?